# Why do I get an exception error when I try output an array?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I have written a simple code that is supposed to output a 2D array.
This is the code:

```java
String month[];
int speedfines[][];

public int speedFines() {
    speedfines = new int[3][2];
    month = new String[2];

    month[0] = "JAN";
    month[1] = "FEB";
    month[2] = " MAR";

    speedfines[0][0] = 128;
    speedfines[0][1] = 135;
    speedfines[0][2] = 139;
    speedfines[1][0] = 155;
    speedfines[1][1] = 129;
    speedfines[1][2] = 175;
    speedfines[2][0] = 129;
    speedfines[2][1] = 130;
    speedfines[2][2] = 185;
    speedfines[3][0] = 195;
    speedfines[3][1] = 155;
    speedfines[3][2] = 221;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(speedfines));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it gives me java exception in thread error.
I am using netbeans 12.0 and I do not have any errors in my code but when I run I get the exception error error
Can someone explain to me what the java exception means and how to fix it if possible.

Comment: You need to make a lot of tests before submitting this kind of questions.
The exception output is very clear that you have an ArrayOutOfBoundException that means you have error with Arrays length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `month` array should be:

```java
month = new String[3];
```

When you set it to `new String[2]`, you are allowing `2` items to be in the array.

Since you set `3` items in the array:

```java
month[0] = "JAN";
month[1] = "FEB";
month[2] = "MAR";
```

It raises the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because at this point index `2` does not exist.

Furthermore, your arrays are defined **outside the function**. Move them inside the function.

The code should be:

```java
public int speedFines() {
    int speedfines[][] = new int[3][2];
    String month[] = new String[3];

    month[0] = "JAN";
    month[1] = "FEB";
    month[2] = "MAR";

    speedfines[0][0] = 128;
    speedfines[0][1] = 135;
    speedfines[0][2] = 139;
    speedfines[1][0] = 155;
    speedfines[1][1] = 129;
    speedfines[1][2] = 175;
    speedfines[2][0] = 129;
    speedfines[2][1] = 130;
    speedfines[2][2] = 185;
    speedfines[3][0] = 195;
    speedfines[3][1] = 155;
    speedfines[3][2] = 221;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(speedfines));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code and made `month = new String [3];` but the error still comes up

Comment: Thank you will change my array values

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the sizes you defined for the arrays `month` and `speedfines`.

For example, you defined size **2** to **month** and tryed to put **3** elements into it. To your code work properly, change the arrays definitions to:

```
speedfines = new int [4][3];
month = new String [3];
```

```
 -------------------
|      |      |     |     ⇒    Size = 3  /  month = new String [3]
 -------------------
   ↑       ↑     ↑
   0       1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

you save 12 items in array 2dimention so you need to do this `speedfines = new int [4][3];`
I think the exception name is ArrayIndexOutOfBounds that show when you put a size of array and give it items bigger than her size